# Помощь с регулярным выражением PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо регулярное выражение, которое будет искать все что начинается с / и заканчивается на цифры. Написал такой вариант, но он не работает:

> /^/$[0-9]+/

Comment: надо экранировать символ `/` в регулярке, как-то так: [`/^\/[0-9]+/$`](https://regex101.com/r/sT6sS7/2). Только выберет строки `/123`, но не `/asd123`. Если надо последнее, тогда [`/^\/.*[0-9]+/$`](https://regex101.com/r/sT6sS7/3)

Comment: В регулярках я слаб( Нужен последний вариант, попробовал поставить это выражение, получаю ошибку: Unknown modifier '$'

Comment: ну да, я опечатался, `$` - конец строки, и он должен быть внутри регулярки, т.е. внутри `/.../`, т.е. надо было так: `/^\/.*[0-9]+$/`. Я же примеры ссылкой оформил, т.е. можно было просто посмотреть и попробовать работу регулярки online

Comment: Образовалась еще одна проблема, нужный мне текст не является началом и концом. Т.е нужно из строки вытянуть этот элемент.

Comment: тогда достаточно убрать символы начала и конца, т.е. `^` и `$`. А как выбирать надо? Например есть текст `/asd123/dsa123asd321` - что в итоге должно получиться? вариантов куча: вся строка, только `/asd123` и `/dsa123` (или `/dsa123asd321`) или только `/dsa123` или еще что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот мой вариант`^\/+.+[0-9]+$`. проверить можно [тут](https://regex101.com/)

если нужное значение в тексте можно использовать такой вариант `\/+.+[0-9]`

```
$re = "/\/+.+[0-9]/"; 
$str = "sadsadas/dfsdf222dfsdfsf7131s2dasdsadasdasda\n"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Получим: `/dfsdf222dfsdfsf7131s2`